# Minimal power circuit for recupating three phase motor drive on DC

Tags: generator, mosfet-driver, induction-motor

A thee phase motor (like an asynchronous motor or an brushless DC motor) can be driven from DC power by using a half bridge on every of the three phases (for example by six FETs) if I'm right.

What is the minimal power circuit that -provided the right control- would be able to also generate on the motor, while feeding back to DC on any occasion? Meaning the circuit should not dissipate any power despite of losses, any power should be transfered from or to the motor.

I guess FETs alone won't do the job, as motor generating voltage may be lower then source DC voltage, so some kind of up conversion would be needed?

Comment: Way not enough information, but in general a full wave (six element) controlled bridge, either MOSFET, or IGBT is most common.  Regenerating from an induction motor is a problem, since the motor peak-to-peak voltage is too high to effectively pump back to the line.  Regenerative energy is typically just dumped to a resistor, or passed on a buss to other drives.

Comment: Sounds like it can't be done.. until someone just does it?

Comment: Of course it can be done, but actually regenerating back to the AC line is exceedingly difficult.  Two Fully controlled bridges are required, with the second "Regen" power bridge connected to an active filter and step down transformer to feed the power back to the line.  This is done, often, but at an extreme cost.  The front end (buss supply unit) costs approximately three times what a simple phase controlled buss supply does, and is much more complex.

Comment: The question is about feeding back to DC source (eg. rechargable battery).

Comment: There is no way to answer without a LOT more details.  In general, batteries can supply much more current than they can absorb, so you would need a secondary high-speed, high-capacity storage medium as an intermediary.  Of course that depends on the system dynamics, how much energy has to be regenerated, the load... Even hybrid cars can only absorb a tiny fraction of regenerative energy due to limitations of the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a variable frequency drive, or VFD. It's a very common piece of commodity hardware, and all of them do exactly what you're describing: take DC voltage and use it to drive an AC induction motor.
[image]

In essence, during motoring the transistors fire in phase with the output AC to the motor. They act as a buck converter, outputting to the motor a voltage less than or equal to the DC bus.

During braking, the transistors fire out of phase with the AC from the motor. They act as a boost converter, meaning the DC voltage output to the bus can be greater than the voltage directly output by the motor.

Of course, once the voltage gets into the DC bus it has nowhere to go. You could use regenerative braking to send that energy back to the line, but you'd need a second six-pack of transistors to do that. Or you could use resistive braking, using a transistor to apply a resistor across the DC bus when the voltage gets too high.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess FETs alone won't do the job, as motor generating voltage may
>   be lower then source DC voltage, so some kind of up conversion would
>   be needed?

Actually FETs alone *can* be enough, as the motor's own inductance can be used to 'up convert' the voltage.

Here's the equivalent circuit of an inductive boost converter:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f47Owm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When FET1 is turned on it connects inductor L1 to Ground, causing current to ramp up and generate a magnetic field in the inductor. A short time later FET1 is switched off. As current in the inductor falls the collapsing magnetic field generates a higher voltage which passes through D1 to the output. C1 stores charge and holds the output voltage up.

Now consider your 3 phase bridge circuit during regenerative braking. Vg represents the instantaneous generator voltage in the motor, and L1 is the stator winding inductance. FET1 is the low-side FET of one phase, and D1 is the body diode of the high-side FET of that phase. C1 is the battery.

The other end of the stator winding is connected to Ground via the low-side FET of that phase, which is turned on. Applying PWM to FET1 dynamically brakes the motor *and* boosts the voltage to charge the battery!

To reduce loss in the diode PWM can be applied to both upper and lower FETs alternately, so when the lower FET is off the upper FET is switched on and bypasses its body diode. In this mode switching losses are minimal and virtually all the power that the motor generates is transferred to the battery. Best of all, no extra components are required.